# Could not find method flutter() for arguments in Visual Studio Code

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

So I am currently trying to build an apk of my app for the Google Play store. I had a similar error with android{} and I was able to fix it by moving up `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` above android{} and it was fixed, but then I got this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/herb/Downloads/morningly/android/app/build.gradle' line: 66

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method flutter() for arguments [build_4k00465lacv9h9hnlvfrbb5oa$_run_closure3@26ab5c57] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

I figured I had to move up the other plugin `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`. I tried moving above line 66 but I still got the same error. Now I am thinking It could be a problem with either build.gradle, or something entirely different. Please, If you have anything insight on how to help, feel free to comment. I desperately want to upload my app.

`app/build.gradle`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.morningly"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    } 
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
} 

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Me again similar problem to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57947444/error-on-build-gradle-in-visual-studio-codeflutter) it seems, try this **apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"** See [Gradle on Flutter with Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56093441/error-running-gradle-on-flutter-with-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Thank you again, my error is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar solution methodology to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57947444/error-on-build-gradle-in-visual-studio-codeflutter) it seems, try this:

```
 apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

As before `flutter{}` method is not known to the `gradle system` until you apply the `plugin/filecode`.

## NOTE

This is a scripted language, where you put things matters, line-by-line interpreted (cannot reference something you have not told the system about) {Could not find method}.